# PHP searching multiple criteria on the database

Tags: php, laravel

```
        if($number_of_rooms == 1 && $country == 'England' && $type == 'Rent') {
            // sth
        }

        else if($number_of_rooms == 2 && $country == 'England' && $type == 'Rent') {
            //sth
        }

        else if($number_of_rooms == 3 && $country == 'England' && $type == 'Rent') {
            //sth
        }

        else if($number_of_rooms == 1 && $country == 'Germany' && $type == 'Rent') {
            //sth
        }

        else if($number_of_rooms == 2 && $country == 'Germany' && $type == 'Rent') {
            //sth
        }

        else if($number_of_rooms == 3 && $country == 'Germany' && $type == 'Rent') {
            //sth
        }

        else if($number_of_rooms == 1 && $country == 'England' && $type == 'Sale') {
            // sth
        }

        else if($number_of_rooms == 2 && $country == 'England' && $type == 'Sale') {
            // sth
        }

        else if($number_of_rooms == 3 && $country == 'England' && $type == 'Sale') {
            // sth
        }

        //
        //
        //
        //
        //
```

This is a simple searching algorithm. Are there any easier ways to do multiple criteria for searching?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Consider to give us some better code snippet.

Comment: It really depends on how your data is structured. For instance, if `$type === 'Rent'`, can you just append to the `WHERE` clause something like ` AND type = "Rent"` regardless of whether the country is England or Germany, and regardless of the number of rooms? Or does the query change too much?

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a Model and database table associated with it and have fields like `number_of_rooms`, `country`, `type` , ... and you are trying to filter your result by users' input.

You can simply pass your `$request`'s inputs to database query builder by controlling each of them with `when`;

```
$result = Apartment::when($request->input('number_of_rooms'), function ($query, $request) {
    return $query->where('number_of_rooms', $request->input('number_of_rooms'));
})->when($request->input('country'), function ($query, $request) {
    return $query->where('country', $request->input('country'));
})->when($request->input('type'), function ($query, $request) {
    return $query->where('type', $request->input('type'));
})
    ->get();
```

But I suggest you to use `spatie/laravel-query-builder` package: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder

It helps you to create dynamic queries based on the `$request` your page gets.

Here is an example;

```
use Spatie\QueryBuilder\QueryBuilder;

$apartments = QueryBuilder::for(Apartment::class)
    ->allowedFilters('number_of_rooms', 'country', 'type')
    ->get();
```

This will automatically create your query with query strings from url. Let's say when you get hit to your page like this:

`/apartments?filter[number_of_rooms]=3&filter[country]=England&filter[type]=Sale`

It will create the result of:

```
Apertment::where('number_of_rooms', 3)
    ->where('country', 'England')
    ->where('type', 'Sale')
    ->get();
```

It allows you to make it work completely dynamic.

It also has `sort` and `including relations` capabilities.

Let's say you also want to let users sort the results by `number_of_rooms`, just update your controller code as:

```
use Spatie\QueryBuilder\QueryBuilder;

$apartments = QueryBuilder::for(Apartment::class)
    ->allowedFilters('number_of_rooms', 'country', 'type')
    ->allowedSorts('number_of_rooms')
    ->get();
```

If request hit as:

`/apartments?filter[number_of_rooms]=3&filter[country]=England&filter[type]=Sale&sort= number_of_rooms`

It will create the response of this:

```
Apertment::where('number_of_rooms', 3)
    ->where('country', 'England')
    ->where('type', 'Sale')
    ->orderBy('number_of_rooms')
    ->get();
```

So; it simplifies all filtering and sorting needs based on request.

Check full documentation here: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v3/introduction